# ES 5.2.2 geohash string match query required

Tags: elasticsearch, geospatial, geohashing

I recently installed ES 5.2.2
I am looking for my data migration and query migration.
I wanted to know, how can we query the points within specified geohash string?

```
GET my_type/_search
{
  "query": {"term": {"location.geohash": "9q8yy"}}
}
```